# Including data from 2 excel forms

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem with my code where it does not include all of the data. I have two excel forms with the same column titles

```
D1
StartDateTime  Model Currency Quantity
7/3/2018 13:35 1     US         3
7/3/2018 13:34 1     US         4   
7/3/2018 13:02 1     US         2
7/3/2018 13:02 1     US         8
7/3/2018 12:01 1     US         3

D2
StartDateTime  Model Currency Quantity
7/3/2018 14:35 11     US         3
7/3/2018 13:34 11     US         4   
7/3/2018 13:02 11     US         2
7/3/2018 13:21 11     US         8
7/3/2018 12:11 11     US         3
```

This data consists of hundreds of rows. 
I tried pd.concat but it does not include all data.
I tried `merge(D1,D2)` it still didn't work.
Can someone please help me? I would like to be able to include both of them into DataBase which will convert StartDateTime to Date. I have done this by

```
dataBase['Date'] = dataBase['StopDateTime'].dt.strftime('%y/%m/%d')
dataBase.sort_values(by='Date')
```

and it serves the purpose.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question using code formatted blocks and provide a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to get helpful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `merged_df = D1.merge(D2, how='outer')`? See the documentation of [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).